# Pandas 0.25.3's clip crashes in certain cases on chunks created by a resample

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a quite narrow problem regarding the result of a time-based groupby in pandas 0.25.3.

I am writing a library to perform various time-based aggregations and met what could be a bug in very specific cases. It doesn't occur in pandas>=1, but I would like to still be able to support pandas 0.25.3 if possible (it is still relevant among our users).

The following case I narrowed down results in an infinite loop of exception catchings in "pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in where" and ultimately a python crash with exit code 134 :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[15.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0,  0.0],
    index=pd.to_datetime(
        [
            "2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
            "2018-01-01 00:25:00.000000",
            "2018-01-01 00:30:00.000000",
            "2018-01-01 00:31:00.000000",
            "2018-01-01 00:47:00.000000",
        ]
    )
)


def clip_low_at_0(x):
    return x.clip(lower=0).sum()


data.resample("30min").agg(clip_low_at_0)
```

My Python version is 3.7.6, pandas 0.25.3.

As a side note, it works well with iterators :

```
for entry, group in data.resample("30min"):
    clip_low_at_0(x=group)
```

And `data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="30min"))` has the exact same issue.

The group causing the problem is this one (the second one):

```
                        0
2018-01-01 00:30:00   0.0
2018-01-01 00:31:00 -10.0
2018-01-01 00:47:00   0.0
```

It seems to happen, as far as I checked :

- With only certain number of values, i.e. 2 values no problem, 3 and 4 there is an issue, 7 no..
- With only certain combinations of values. This one triggers it, some don't, some do.
- With any index value, it doesn't seem related.
- The position of the group matters

Actually, by digging a bit further, it seems that the Series generated by the group that causes the error on `.clip()` is corrupted. Trying to `.copy()` it fails, and a few other methods like serialization ones end with an error. Maybe I'm not using correctly the group and agg, but then would there be another nice way using pandas to compute this ?

What bothers me is that it seems to work in a great deal of cases, and this exact case does in pandas>=1.0.0.

If it happens to be a real bug, I would of course report to pandas' team in an issue. (edit: it doesn't seem that pandas encourages bug reports on older versions)

edit: To clarify, I would like to :

1) Know if it's actually a misuse or an actual bug on the groupby/agg side

2) If there is a better workaround than doing the clip myself (x.loc[x < 0] = 0). Because this group may lead to other issues in the future with other functions used for aggregation. I want to keep the resampling approach not to have to handle the indexes myself if possible, I actually do some other aggregations using the same structure.

Comment: Could you please state your exact question? Are you looking for a workaround? Why can't you just make use of the iterator approach?

Comment: @amain I just updated the question, the obvious workaround is to do the clip manually but I was wondering If I was doing it right, and would like to keep the group approach for its advantages in index management.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, but it seems to be limited to the use of `clip()`, doesn't it? Other functions like `round()` etc seem to run fine. So this definitely looks like a Pandas bug to me.

As a **general workaround** you could directly use *numpy* functions instead of Pandas functions in your aggregation function:

```
def clip_low_at_0(x):
    return numpy.clip(x, a_min=0, a_max=None).sum()
```

Still, for the sake of completeness: a **specific workaround** (and a *weird* one, too) for the buggy behaviour of Pandas' `clip()` is to explicitly set an upper limit. Although I have not gained an understanding of *why* this works, it actually does (here, at least):

```
def clip_low_at_0(x):
    # using numpy's 'double' dtype max value here, but this could
    # be replaced with sys.maxsize or any other sensible constant
    maxval = numpy.finfo('d').max
    return x.clip(lower=0, upper=maxval).sum()
```

Last (you already know that): there's no need to clip values inside the aggregation function, you can just apply it beforehand to the whole DataFrame:

```
data.clip(lower=0).resample("30min").sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not exactly restricted to the `clip` as the `Series` object created is not a correct one (`x.copy()`fails for instance) and so other problems could arise with other methods.
But it seems to be a tricky bug so I'd be fine with the workarounds offered :)           
(I can't clip before as I actually apply programmatically several aggregation functions in my program, but numpy, manual clip or higher limit would do)